# Why is my PowerShell Code deleting my folder when I am trying to move files over?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I am trying to move all files that are 2 years and older to a different directory.

But my code doesn't move my files, deletes the destination folder, and says that the destination folder doesn't exist.

I know that this works when it is not in a function, but I need it to be in a function because I am dealing with multiple directories where I shouldn't need to replicate code.

```
Function Move ($oldPath, $years, $newPath)
{
    <#Moving File#>
    $years = $years * -1
    $date = [DateTime]::Now.AddYears($years)
    Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $oldPath))
    {
        if($file.LastWriteTime -eq $date -or $file.LastWriteTime -lt $date)
        {
            Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $newPath
        }

    }
}
$oldPath = insert source file path here
$years = 2
$newPath = insert destination file path here
Move ($oldPath, $years, $newPath)
```

Comment: `move` is an alias for `Move-Item`. Creating a function called `Move` doesn't overwrite that alias. I would name your function something else.

Comment: The proper way to call a PowerShell function with positional parameters is `Move $oldpath $years $newPath`. Otherwise `($oldPath, $years, $newPath)` is parsed as a single object bound to the `oldPath` parameter.